# R show/hide points

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization, ggiraph

everybody.

I am using `R` and `ggplot2`. I have a chart and there are multiple points on it (Each of them has different colors. Red, blue, yellow, etc). I am using also `R Shiny` and `ggiraph` package to have `click` events on `legends`. Once, I click `legend`, I am rendering new chart based on filter criteria and it is fine.

Problem. When any color is removed from dataset (for example red), `legend` (with name red) is hided also. Also, I try to hide points but this case legends are hided also.

What kind of solution I need this case ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create your own discrete scale:

```
library(ggiraph)
library(ggplot2)

z <- ggplot(iris,aes(x=Sepal.Length,y=Sepal.Width,color=Species, tooltip = Species))+
  geom_point_interactive() + 
  scale_color_manual_interactive(values = c(setosa = "red", versicolor = "green", virginica = "yellow", yoyo = "black"),
                                 data_id = c(setosa = "setosa", versicolor = "versicolor", virginica = "virginica", yoyo = "yoyo"),
                                 tooltip = c(setosa = "setosa", versicolor = "versicolor", virginica = "virginica", yoyo = "yoyo"),
                                 limits = c("setosa", "versicolor", "virginica", "yoyo"))
girafe(ggobj = z)
```

[image]

Comment: no problem. If you are new to ggplot2, you should read that part: https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_manual.html

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `plotly`:

```
library(plotly)
library(ggplot2)
#Code
ggplotly(ggplot(iris,aes(x=Sepal.Length,y=Sepal.Width,color=Species))+
  geom_point())
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for reply.

I tried `plotly` project, but my ggplot object has background_image. It seems, that `plotly` doesn't respect background_images. Also, I posted question about it yesterday.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65156155/r-renderplotly-has-white-background